# Multithreading bruteforce script python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, brute-force

So I'm writing this bruteforce script in python3 and it works fine but it is obiouvsly very slow, both becouse python is not very indicated for this stuff and because I don't know how to implement multithreading. I'm only creating this script because I'm interested in ethical hacking and I want to see how multithreading would make it better.
So the interested part of code is this:

```
def bruto(charset1, maxlength1):
   return(''.join(candidate) for candidate in  chain.from_iterable(product(charset, repeat=i) for i in range(1, maxlength + 1)))

for guess1 in bruto(charset,maxlength):
    guess_hash1 = getattr(hashlib, algorithm)(bytes(guess1, 'utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

How can I implement multithreading? Thank in advance and sorry for the noobiness

Answer (score 1):

Using threading with cpu-bound tasks will make your application slower due to 
[global interpreter lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython). You should use `multiprocessing` instead.

The simplest way would be to use `ProcessPoolExecutor` to calcuate hash values

```
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor

def get_hash(guess):
    return guess, getattr(hashlib, algorithm)(bytes(guess, "utf-8")).hexdigest()

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    guesses = bruto(charset, maxlength)
    all_hashes = executor.map(get_hash, guesses)
```

Keep in mind that this might also slow your application :) because of the IPC overhead. If single `get_hash` is too quick you could set some bigger chunksize in `executor.map(chunksize=100)`

Python parallelism is full of suprises :)